# perl read line-by-line from scalar variable

Tags: perl, io, www-mechanize

From scraping a website, I have an html file in a scalar variable, $res.
I want to read the html file in $res line-by-line. For example, while (my $line = )...

Do I need to print $res to a text file and then read in the text file ?

Comment: Please show how you're fetching the HTML in the first place and explain what you want to do with it. The module you're using may offer a better way to do what you want, e.g. WWW::Mechanize has a `links` method to pull all links from a page so you don't have to parse the raw HTML yourself.

Comment: $res has the entire contents of the html file. I am using WWW::Mechanize, but I want text. I use Mechanize to input a sequence in a textarea, choose some variable and submit. The results page is a table which I would like to filter out some results and print the others to a file.

Comment: I am using: my $res = $mech->content(raw => 1). I know I could do: my $res = $mech->content( format => text), but this results in no delimiters between columns of the table. For example, the table has 4.3  5.6  5  34. Using format text, I get 4.35.6534.

Comment: Ah, OK, so I can just parse $res with HTML::Parser or something similar. Thank you, toolic !

Comment: @Matthew There's also [HTML::TreeBuilder](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder).

Comment: Tree::Builder looks very helpful. Thank you, ThisSuitIsBlackNot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address [the Y part of this problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), yes, you can treat a scalar variable as an input source and use Perl's input processing features. You just `open` a reference to the variable:

```
open my $fh, '<', \$res;
my $header = <$fh>;        # first "line" of $res
while (my $line = <$fh>) { # next "line" of $res
    ...
}
```

Comment: This works and does it very elegantly; in only 2 lines of code. I don't need the $header part. You're a Perl ninja, mob !

Answer (score 0):

You may use `IO::Scalar` module.

**`man IO::Scalar`** :

```
use 5.005;
use IO::Scalar;
$data = "My message:\n";

### Open a handle on a string, read it line-by-line, then close it:
$SH = new IO::Scalar \$data;
while (defined($_ = $SH->getline)) {
    print "Got line: $_";
}
```

`while(<$SH>)` works too.